# Is grails run-war suitable for production?

Tags: grails

We have a green-field deployment opportunity, and it seems simple to have grails manage the servlet container for us instead of installing it through the OS package manager.

Understanding that `run-app` is never suitable for deployment, is `run-war` a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to deploy a Grails app to production is to run `grails war` to build a .war file and deploy that to your container. According to the docs `run-war`

> is useful for quick deployment and/or testing

so on that basis, it seems that it's not intended for production deployments